# How to restart a process using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64

Every time I accidentally unplug my Logitech keyboard, the "LCore.exe" process does not respond. I have to manually end the process and start it again.
I want to create a .bat file to do this for me, but I don't know how.

I tried using this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
taskkill /im LCore.exe
start "C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\LCore.exe"
```

Comment: What does not work ? Closing or restarting ?

Comment: Both. I've tried your suggestion by adding the "/f" and it worked.  
However, starting the process doesn't seem to work. A command prompt appears with "C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\LCore.exe" as the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add /f to taskkill, this will force killing the process.

A hack to solve the other problem:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\LCore.exe"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first command asks the program to close. If it's hung it can't react.

See `taskkill /?` and see the `/f` for force parameter.

For a non console program a `WM_Close` message is posted to the main window (ie as if you clicked the red X button on the titlebar). When using `/f` `TerminateProcess` is used (as stopping a process on the process tab of task manager).

From Help

> An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window, by processing the WM_CLOSE message and calling the DestroyWindow function only if the user confirms the choice.
>
> By default, the DefWindowProc function calls the DestroyWindow function to destroy the window.

and

> Remarks
>
> The TerminateProcess function is used to unconditionally cause a process to exit. The state of global data maintained by dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) may be compromised if TerminateProcess is used rather than ExitProcess.
>
> TerminateProcess initiates termination and returns immediately. This stops execution of all threads within the process and requests cancellation of all pending I/O. The terminated process cannot exit until all pending I/O has been completed or canceled.
>
> A process cannot prevent itself from being terminated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Open Notepad,
    Paste the code below,
    Save as "Whateveryouwant.BAT",

    **Done!**
    By running this you will force kill the logitech core process, and then start it again.
```

`taskkill /f /im LCore.exe start "" "C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\LCore.exe"`